# Merge tags [802.11] and [wireless-networking]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

Merge tags [802.11](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/802.11) and [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking).

Considering [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) has [wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wifi) as a synonym …

Comment: I think you've been told a couple of times that `[retag-requests]` should not be tagged `[bug]`. Please consider for the next time.

Comment: @slhck I don’t think they have the goal of reaching community consensus.

Comment: Well, it's not a `bug` due to a programming error or any technical fault. This question is of no interest to the developer team at all. Community consensus on whether a tag should be merged with another is expressed through votes on the question itself. It has always been like that. You can see the cross-correlation by looking at the related tags for both `discussion` and `retag-request`.

Comment: In future, keep in mind that [bug] is not a synonym for [what-irks-me] and is reserved for system/development issues

Comment: @kinokijuf please don't create useless meta tags

Comment: @Sathya See random’s comment.

Comment: @kinokijuf it doesn't mean you go create it.

Comment: 802.11 == Wi-Fi.  Wi-Fi & 802.11 are *subsets* of wireless-networking (as is Bluetooth, ZigBee, GSM, etc...).

Comment: Brilliant community bot--bumped a 5 yr old status-declined thread because there are no upvoted or accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

There's more:

- [802.11g](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/802.11g) x 13
- [802.11n](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/802.11n) x 59

Not too certain if 802.11* should be mapped to [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) or not

Comment: I have a bad feeling about merging those 802.11 into wireless networking - which is why I haven't taken action sooner. Perhaps we could merge *11g & *11n into a plain old 802.11 tag.

Comment: @studiohack tbh I'm not keen on either.

Comment: Counter argument to consider: People troubleshooting their `n` settings might benefit from their own [tag:802.11n], the same goes for people trying to support older [tag:802.11g] standards.